# the of navbar drop down menu hiding behind card and fillters

Tags: javascript, angular

i am beginner so I am trying to make a website for just learning the language that was been used is Javascript and faced this problem that  dropdown menu hiding behind cards and the filter, any one faced the same problem ?  and this is the pics

any help ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXPS.png)

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <ng-template #anonymousUser>
          <li *ngIf="auth.user" class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login">login</a>
          </li>
        </ng-template>
        <li
          *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else anonymousUser"
          ngbDropdown
          class="nav-item dropdown"
        >
          <a
            ngbDropdownToggle
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            id="navbarDropdown"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            {{ user.displayName }}
          </a>
          <ul
            ngbDropdownMenu
            class="dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
          >
            <li>
              <a
                class="dropdown-item"
                href="dashboard"
                aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
                >Dashboard</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="admin/products">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="admin/publish">publish</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a (click)="logout()" class="dropdown-item" href="home">logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: would be helpful to also add the code (html + css) for the rest of the component - where cards with flags are being rendered. This seems to be a css z-index issue.

Comment: Please also share your css code for better analysis of your problem. Just for a first question have you played around with the css property z-index yet? This might fix your problem.

Comment: No I did't play with css property z-index.

Comment: Alrighty, you might want to try it on the dropdown-menu. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the z-index of the `dropdown-menu`
Like this,

```
.dropdown-menu{
    z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I have just noticed that by default Bootstrap uses z-index of 1000 on the dropdown-menu, so anything above that should lift it in front.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue due to z-index. If you want to display the drop-down menu at the front then you can increase it's z-index so that it won't hide behind any cards. Make sure that z-index is greater than any other element which might hide the drop-down menu. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).